# variable getElementbyId inside function

Tags: javascript, html, css

I can't  understand one thing. I have a function which accepts as a parameter the id of a dom element:

For Example

**HTML**

```
<ol id="ol">
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
</ol>
```

**JS**

```
function whatever(elem) {
    var element = document.getElementById(elem);
}
```

**Initialization**

```
whatever(ol)
```

Why when I do `console.log(element)` within the function, it is showing `null`? What am I missing?

Comment: [`document.getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) expects the id to search for as a string. -> `whatever("ol")`

Comment: Try `whatever("ol")`

Comment: @Lauromine I need to make something universal not only for "ol" thats why I am trying to make a function

Comment: Three people have told you now that you need to pass the element identifier as a string...(unless `ol` is defined as a JS variable).

Comment: What do you want to achieve? If you just want to have your "own" function  which does the same thing as `getElementById` simply do `var whatever = document.getElementById`

Comment: @Lauromine That won't work, of course, unless you invoke `whatever` as `whatever.call(document...`. Simply calling `whatever('ol")` will yield an illegal invocation error.

Answer (score 2):

`whatever("ol")` should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem is twofold:

1. You've got a scope problem. The variable `element` is defined and assigned within the `whatever` function, which means you can't see it outside of that function. You want to return the result of calling document.getElementId from your function.

   ```
   function whatever(id) {
       return document.getElementById(id);
   }
   ```
2. You must pass a string representing the id of the element to your function.

   ```
   var element = whatever("ol");
   ```

With these two things in place `element` will now be a reference to the correct HTML element.